# como consumir un web service rest

Tags: javascript, html

Quería consultar como consumir un web service rest, con el objetivo de tomar los datos obtenidos y en base a ellos, actualizar los iconos de un mapa.
el web service del que necesito obtener los datos es el siguiente:

http://172.25.150.171:8080/TestDummy/webresources/test/data

y los datos que están en formato json son estos:

```
> [{"date":"2019/05/09","hour":"16:36:01","lat":"-33.4381056","lon":"-70.639616","ot":"95","otname":"EVASION
> CONTROL","qctrl":"10","qfault":"25","idstate":"1","obs":"esto es una
> observacion!!!!"},{"date":"2019/05/09","hour":"16:36:01","lat":"-33.4415939","lon":"-70.6606995","ot":"98","otname":"EMISIONES
> DIESEL","qctrl":"10","qfault":"25","idstate":"1","obs":"esto es una
> observacion!!!!"},{"date":"2019/05/09","hour":"16:36:01","lat":"-33.448326","lon":"-70.6728874","ot":"102","otname":"INSPECCION
> TAXIMETROS","qctrl":"10","qfault":"25","idstate":"1","obs":"esto es
> una observacion!!!!"}]
```

la idea es que sea con el método get, sin botones, que cuando la página se actualice cada cierto tiempo (2 minutos por ejemplo), según los datos del web service los iconos cambien de color. espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

tengo un archivo html donde esta el mapa, que no lo pongo porque es algo largo y el siguiente es un archivo .js donde actualizo los marcadores. necesito poder hacer algo similar pero con los datos obtenidos del web service. gracias de antemano.

```
    function ActualMarker(){
     var rIcon = L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'marcadores/marker-icon-violet.png',
         })
     var rIcon2 = L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'marcadores/marker-icon-green.png',
         })
     var rIcon3 = L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'marcadores/icon-red.png',
         })
     var rIcon4 = L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'marcadores/marker-icon-yellow.png',
         })
     var rIcon5 = L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'marcadores/marker-icon-black.png',
         })      
     var rIcon6 = L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'marcadores/marker-icon-orange.png',
         })  

     var fecha = new Date();
     var segundos = fecha.getSeconds();

     for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i ) 
       {      
       if (segundos >= 0 && segundos < 10){
       L.marker( [markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng], {icon: rIcon} )
       .bindPopup( 'Tráfico Lento' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[1].lat, markers[1].lng], {icon: rIcon} )
       .bindPopup( 'Tráfico Lento' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[2].lat, markers[2].lng], {icon: rIcon} )
       .bindPopup( 'Tráfico Lento' ).addTo( cities );

       }else if (segundos >= 11 && segundos < 20){

       L.marker( [markers[2].lat, markers[2].lng], {icon: rIcon2} )
       .bindPopup( 'Operativo Carabineros' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[3].lat, markers[3].lng], {icon: rIcon2} )
       .bindPopup( 'Operativo Carabineros' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[4].lat, markers[4].lng], {icon: rIcon2} )
       .bindPopup( 'Operativo Carabineros' ).addTo( cities );

     } else if (segundos >= 20 && segundos < 30){


       L.marker( [markers[4].lat, markers[4].lng], {icon: rIcon3} )
       .bindPopup( 'Vehículo Confiscado' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[5].lat, markers[5].lng], {icon: rIcon3} )
       .bindPopup( 'Vehículo Confiscado' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[6].lat, markers[6].lng], {icon: rIcon3} )
       .bindPopup( 'Vehículo Confiscado' ).addTo( cities );

     } else if (segundos >= 30 && segundos < 40){

       L.marker( [markers[6].lat, markers[6].lng], {icon: rIcon4} )
       .bindPopup( 'Inspector' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[7].lat, markers[7].lng], {icon: rIcon4} )
       .bindPopup( 'Inspector' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[1].lat, markers[1].lng], {icon: rIcon4} )
       .bindPopup( 'Inspector' ).addTo( cities );

     } else if (segundos >= 40 && segundos < 50){

       L.marker( [markers[5].lat, markers[5].lng], {icon: rIcon5} )
       .bindPopup( 'Accidente Tránsito' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[3].lat, markers[3].lng], {icon: rIcon5} )
       .bindPopup( 'Accidente Tránsito' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[2].lat, markers[2].lng], {icon: rIcon5} )
       .bindPopup( 'Accidente Tránsito' ).addTo( cities );

     } else {

       L.marker( [markers[6].lat, markers[6].lng], {icon: rIcon6} )
       .bindPopup( 'Vehículo de Carga Detenido' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[4].lat, markers[4].lng], {icon: rIcon6} )
       .bindPopup( 'Vehículo de Carga Detenido' ).addTo( cities );

       L.marker( [markers[3].lat, markers[3].lng], {icon: rIcon6} )
       .bindPopup( 'Vehículo de Carga Detenido' ).addTo( cities );
     }
}

}
      setInterval(ActualMarker, 10000);
```

Comment: una de las recomendaciónes que te doy es que uses `axios` o `ajax` para consumir  el web-services, siendo el primero de mi preferencia. Y si quieres que funcione desde el inicio con una función anónima debería bastar

Comment: Tu problema es llamar al webservice, entender la respuesta o que parte? como esta la pregunta, es poco claro donde tenes el problema.

Comment: mi problema es que no logro consumir los datos, he intentado con ajax y otras formas pero siempre tengo errores. una vez que logre obtener los datos, ahi tengo que usarlos para que los iconos del mapa cambien. pero primero como dije lo que necesito es lograr consumir los datos del web service.

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo del progreso hasta ahora? lo que as intentando?

Comment: edite la pregunta y puse algo del código espero puedas ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: utiliza `fetch()`

Comment: Para consumir servicios hay varias opciones. Podrías utilizar AJAX de jQuery pero es algo pesada la librería y no la recomendaría si solamente la utilizarías para consumir el servicio. Otra opción es utilizar fetch() siempre y cuando el navegador lo soporte. Finalmente se encuentra axios que es una librería interesante. Las dos últimas utilizan promesas que es una característica muy importante en la programación web moderna así que te recomendaría alguna de esas. P.D.: En el código que pusiste no se ve que hayas intentando consumir el servicio.